# slidedown and z-index issue?

Tags: jquery, css, slidedown

this is my [site](http://attila-naghi.com/) . So , if you press the login link (up - left) you can see sliding down a `div` . It works, the problem is when i starting to play with ctrl + scroll , everything from the `div` is starting to change it's position

this is the js and html code :

```
<div id="container" class="container" style= "">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".login").click(function(){
                $(".login-data").slideDown();
            });
            $(".close-login").click(function(){
                $(".login-data").slideUp();
            })
        });
        </script>
        <div class ="preheader">
            <span><a href ="#"> My Account </a></span> | <span><a href ="#" class="login">Login </a></span> 
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div class ="login-data">
            <form action ="#" method="POST">
                <div class ="login-inputs">
                    <input type="text" placeholder= "Username"><br>
                    <input type="password" placeholder= "Password"><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login">
                </div>
                <div class ="close-login">
                    X
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

.......
and this is the css :

```
.preheader{
    float:right; 
    padding:3px
    ;margin-bottom: 5px;
    z-index:-1;
}
.login-data{
  padding :10px;
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #8AB928;
  width:25%;
  display:none;
  z-index:1000;
  /*float:right;*/
  position:absolute;
  left:60%;
}
.login-inputs{
  float:left;
  width:60%;
}
.close-login{
  float:left;
  width:30%;
}
.close-login:hover{
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #555;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

What should i do to make this work ?

Comment: by ctrl+scroll you mean zooming in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `position:absolute` property of `.login-data` is relating to your body. When you are zooming the `#container` is getting smaller/bigger, but the `.login-data` is still orientating on the body. The `.login-data` needs to relate to the `#container`.

Try adding `position: relative` to `#container` and set `right: 0;` to `.login-data`. Now the `.login-data` orientates on the `#container` and is on the right top of `#container`. It looks good when i starting to play with ctrl + scroll.

```
#container {
  ...
  position:relative;
  ...
}
.login-data{
  padding :10px;
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #8AB928;
  width:25%;
  display:none;
  z-index:1000;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
}
```

Greetings